# What happens if I insert a disk for a game I have already downloaded digitally?

Tags: ps4

My aunt bought me a disk copy of Star Wars: Battlefront II, but she didn't know I had the digital version installed. What happens if I insert the disk?

Comment: Seems like you're all set up to try it out. The OS will probably show you that you loaded the game disc for Star Wars: Battlefront II. And that's it. You might be able to install the game even, depending on what versions and editions. So you can install the game twice. Awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing, unless the physical version has any different content - Skyrim Legendary Edition, for example, would download a separate Skyrim game if you already had the original Skyrim.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing at all, as long as the games are the same.